# can a multi column fk reference multiple tables?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, rdbms

I have 3 tables
part, build, & buildpart
buildpart is m:m.
I was wondering if i could include the two columns of buildpart that are referencing part & build respectively in a single fk & make it clustered. I've been searching for about 4 hours now & I think this is not possible for some valid reason. Although I think MacConnel disagrees here http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ForeignKeysCanOnlyReferenceOneTable.

Answer (score 1):

A foreign key can reference multiple tables but the values of that foreign key must then match values in *both* tables, not just either one. It doesn't seem to make any sense to combine the part and build into one column because that wouldn't represent your many to many relationship.

Answer (score 0):

No, a foreign key constraint goes between the primary table and the foreign table.  So you could create a clustered index on the primary table that covers both columns (part_id and build_id), then 1 foreign key from buildpart to build and one foreign key from buildpart to part.

HTH

Comment: Whether indexes are clustering or not has nothing to do with foreign key constraints.